# ellipsis mouseover appears when ellipsis is not activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this `<th><a></a></th>` dynamically filled with movie titles.
I use ellipsis to shorten the title when it is too long. The user can browse throught the titles with two arrows (prev, next).

```
The Dark Kn... **< prev&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;next >** (in mouseover "The Dark Knight")
```

"click next"

```
Iron Man 3 **< prev&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;next >** (in mouseover nothing)
```

etc.

The ellipsis works fine. If the user mouseovers the shortened title I want to show the full title. That works too. 
The problem is that after a mouseover in a shortened title if the user keeps browsing then every time he mouseovers a new title (either shortened or not) the same full title is shown.

```
The Dark Kn... **< prev&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;next >** (in mouseover "The Dark Knight")
```

"click next"

```
Iron Man 3 **< prev&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;next >** (in mouseover "The Dark Knight")
```

etc.

It goes away only with a page refresh. Does anyone know how to fix it??

Here is a sample code:

```
var MoviesCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){

        this.movieHeaders = '<th colspan="4" class="showMovies"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="movies1 shortened" title="" style="width:78%;"></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon-link previous movies1" title=""> < prev </a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon-link next movies1" title=""> next > </a></th>';

    }

    renderMovies: function(){

        for(var i=0;i<this.movieTitles.codes.length;i++){
            $('.movies1', this.el).html(this.getMovieTitle)
        }

        $(".shortened",this.el).ellipsis(true,false);
    }

});
```

Comment: How to fix a code you can't see?

Comment: the website is built in backbone.js and the code structure is a disaster at the time. The ellipsis is used in other places as well and it works perfect. I just ask if somebody has faced this problem before and if it is an ellipsis bug!!

Comment: We don't need (or want) all the code you have, please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).